# Uncaught TypeError accordion is not a function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have try to active accordion to top smooth scroll but shown error is accordion is not function. I have already add jquery min (version:3.3.1) file.

```
<script>

$(function() {
        $("#accordionEx").accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content",
            active: 0,
            animate: 300
        });
        $('#accordionEx h2').bind('click',function(){
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                theOffset = $(self).offset();
                $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: theOffset.top - 100 });
            }, 310);
        });
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Did you added the `jquery ui` library @Sneha Patel

Answer (score 2):

Please add exactly after the jquery library

```
// After your jquery library
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

This will help you.

For more details about accordion, refer to this link: [accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)